# If CNOTs and single qubit gates are universal then why do we need to prove that controlled U operations can be composed by them as well?

Tags: quantum-gate, gate-synthesis, nielsen-and-chuang

In the book by Chuang and Nielsen they prove that controlled U operations can be made out of CNOTs and single qubit gates. But then they go on to prove that they are universal by showing that every n by n matrix can be decomposed into two level matrices and then to CNOTs and single qubit gates.  But if so, then why can't we prove this way that controlled U can be too, decomposed to them. Since a controlled U is after all an n by n matrix. Why is there a separate proof for them?

Comment: Because it might be more insightful? These gates might be more relevant? Because the construction you get is simpler?  Or just for educational purposes?  This is a bit like asking why a math textbook first proves Cauchy-Schwarz and then later Hölder's inequality, given that the former is a special case.

Comment: But is this indeed the case here? They give a pretty lengthy and complicated proof for this . What's the point if later it can be proven by the universality.  Why do they have to show controlled U and not other special cases?

Comment: I thought, but I am not sure.  Maybe their universality proof which is based on factorization of unitary into two level matrices doesn't hold for controlled U just like it doesn't hold for CNOT

Comment: I don't think the comparison to Cauchy Schwar is valid. As it's a theorem. But here what's the point

Comment: Unlike the universality result, which is a random claim?

Answer (score 2):

Constructing controlled-U out of single qubit rotations and cNOT is part of the proof of universality of single qubit rotations and cNOT.

The bit of Nielsen & Chuang that you're referring to decomposes an arbitrary unitary in terms of gates such as controlled-controlled-....-controlled-U. See, for example, Fig 4.16 (P. 193 of 2002 printing). But that gate is built out of controlled-U. See, for example, Fig. 4.10 (P. 184). (although Exercise 4.28 gives you a different construction without work qubits). So, you need to construction of controlled-U for the whole thing to work.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by figure 4.16 and 4.10. In which pages?  I don't find them.  According to what I see their proof is based on decomposition to two level matrices and then , each of them they decompose to single qubit matrices and CNOTs.

Comment: I thought, but I am not sure. Maybe their universality proof which is based on factorization of unitary into two level matrices doesn't hold for controlled U just like it doesn't hold for CNOT

Comment: what do you understand by "two level matrices"?

Comment: One would have assumed that the OP would have checked that this is not used in the proof ...

Comment: I am sorry, daftwullie but I do think it isn't used in the proof. So what you said is wrong. As to two level matrix is a matrix which acts non trivially only on two elements

Comment: @bilanush So, according to you, *how* do N&C go from having a two-level matrix to decomposing it in terms of cNOT and single qubit unitaries?

Comment: Ha ok.  Sorry. So you say they are using a single U operation which is controlled by other qubits. That's a legit answer , upvoted! But don't you think there might be something deeper? I mean, you disagree with me that controlled U operations are not included in the first decomposition to a multiple of two level matrices? Just like CNOT isn't included. CNOT is a 4x4 matrix so this too should have been included in the proof. It isn't. So why couldn't be that U operations aren't included either?